# Alternatives to MS Code Contracts Runtime checking (not static checking)

Tags: c#

I am looking for a lightweight alternative to MS Code Contracts.  Basically an alternative for Contract.Requires and Contact.Ensure.  I don't even care about the rewriting - just something simple I can plug in for checking parameters and results.  For example, I did find http://lightcontracts.codeplex.com/ but this is now 4 years old.

Greg

Comment: Just for curiosity, what "heavyweight" did you find in code contracts?

Comment: Well, overall I like it, but it's in a Silverlight app and it when I try to enable runtime checking, I get an error saying that RuntimeContractsFlags cannot be added to list of known types as it already exists.  An error I have not been able to resolve.

Comment: I'm sure, that searching for alternative isn't a right way in your case. It is better to solve your particular problem.

Comment: Yes, I am sure you are right about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out [CuttingEdge.Conditions](http://conditions.codeplex.com/) or [Lakad Rules](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/11/23/net-application-block-for-validation-and-business-rules.html) which is part of the Lokad Shared Libraries:

Comment: Sadly it seems that there's no new download since 2011 :(

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, I think development of most libs has come to a stop since MS code contracts are a good solution in most cases.

Comment: @blueling, thanks, that does looking interesting and I do like the fluent interface.

Comment: @blueling BTW CodeContracts are good enought but contracts' compiler is still a MS Research project. This is very sad. CodeContracts were introduced in .NET 4.0.. Are we talking about 2009-early 2010. And CC compiler is very slow, and brutally slow when activating static checking. I'm still wondering how would perform a new library implementing Design by Contract using PostSharp. I believe it would be the definitive solution, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't R# do this already even?